# Problem to implement multi tasking in node-red

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, node-red, multitasking

Is there a way to implement multitasking in NodeRed? I mean, I have different flows and when I inject true to one of them they take some minutes to do some work. So if I try to inject another flow it will wait all the flows finish their works.

[image: Here an example]

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS (and all applications that run on top of it e.g. Node-RED) are singled threaded.

NodeJS uses an event loop with tasks being placed on the queue and executed in order until that task yeilds (usually due to needing to do IO)

Without knowing what Orange and Red nodes in your flow I can't guess what they are doing, but if they are not yielding then you will have to wait. Node should be written to use asynchronous patterns where ever possible and not to block.

Comment: Single nodes are developed in an asynchronous way. The thing I noticed is that even if I did that, other work have to wait that other flows arrive at the end of them, that is at the last node of the flow (for example an output). Maybe I have to periodically send messages to the outputs in order to not stack at intermediate nodes?

Comment: Your best bet is to discuss this on the Node-RED during our Slack instance, and be prepared to store the code of any custom nodes you have written